# What is the best way to publish RSS Feed on Facebook?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook, rss, publish

What is the best way to publish an rss feed or a sitemap to facebook?

I am using google app engine as the platform and the python language

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a library that can do the feed to Facebook publication. There are a few apps that do this, like [this one](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=5315590686).

One an Application is granted the **publish_stream** [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) it can post on behalf of the User (or Page) using the [api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post). There is a [Python SDK](http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk) which should work on AppEngine.